# Why is it that $\int (\sec^2(x) + \csc^2(x))\,dx = -2\cot(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

Why is it that $$\int (\sec^2(x) + \csc^2(x))\,dx = -2\cot(2x)\,?$$

I guess, to me, it isn't immediately clear in an *intuitive* way that this is the case without pulling out a table of integrals and plugging things in. Is there some nice way to think of this (graphically, via an argument/short proof, etc)?

Comment: Why should an integration result be "intuitive"? What's intuitive about $\int x^{-1}\,dx=\log x+C$?

Comment: No there is no short way out or any "intuitive" method you are asking for. In integration, many results are not at all intuitive. The results look mostly random.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wasn't suggesting that one exists, however I was hoping that one would. I'm in Calc II, and I find that a lot of calculus concepts and results are intuitive, in one sense or another (at minimum, there's some line of reasoning that can be followed). I struggle to remember these sort of things by rote, but do very well if I have some deeper understanding and can "come up" with the results on the spot, or at least fill in the details. Unfortunately, we're tasked with recalling a table of integrals many pages long, with many unintuitive results such as this.

Comment: Anyone who tries to memorize pages of integrals is going about things the wrong way. You learn four: $\int x^n$, $\int e^x$, $\int\sin x$, $\int\cos x$ (and you don't even need the last two, you can get them from the formulas for the derivative of the sine and cosine functions). Then, you learn a few formulas for reducing everything else to the four you've learned: $\int cf(x)$, $\int(f(x)+g(x))$, integration by substitution, integration by parts, the partial fractions technique (which is really algebra, not integration), and you're done.

Comment: Then, you do a few hundred exercises, and by the end of that you will know what $\int(x^2+1)^{-1}$ is, and what $\int\sec^2x$ is, and many more besides, without ever looking at a table of pages of integrals. By the way, I don't think "intuitive" means what you think it means. If you need a line of reasoning to get a result, that means the result is *not* intuitive. Intuition is the *opposite* of reasoning.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm afraid I totally disagree. Memorizing the integrals of $\sec^2{x},\sec{x},\tan{x},\cos{x}, \sin{x},-\csc{x}\cot{x},-\csc^2{x},\csc{x},\cot{x},\ln{x},x^n,\frac{f'(x)}{f(x},f'(x)e^{f(x)}, \frac{1}{x}$ and many more besides is extremely useful and often **neccessary** if you want to deal with some particualrly nasty integrals quickly. eg trying to integrate $\sec{x}$ is rather longer usng substitution than simply regurgiatating the result $\ln(\sec{x}+\tan{x})$.

Comment: @A-level rather than memorize the integral of $\sec^2x$, memorize the derivative of $\tan x$. $\int\tan x$ is easy using $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$ and substitution $u=\cos x$. $\int\log x$ is easy using parts, $u=\log x$, $dv=\dx$. $f'(x)/f(x)$ and $f'(x)e^{f(x)}$ are just special cases of substitution. Some of the others were already on the list I gave. You're probably right about $\int\sec x$, so add that one to my list.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree that you'd fare OK if you only learnt the derivatives of things like $\tan{x}$ and then applied them to integrate things like $\sec^2{x}$, but I beluev that at the end of the day it is faster to memoroze the inregral as well. Integarting $\tan{x}$ is also simply much faster if you know the result, as opposed to spenidng longer using substitution. Again, the same applies to $\ln{x}$, and $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ $f'(x)e^{f(x)}$

Comment: @A-level can we agree that if "we're tasked with recalling a table of integrals many pages long," then we're going about it the wrong way?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I suppose I do agree if the list is multiple pages long, but I think about 2 pages is fine.

Comment: @GerryMyerson anyway, whatever works for each of us is fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe rewrite the integrand first?

\begin{align*}
\int \sec^2 x + \csc^2 x \, dx &= \int \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x \sin^2 x} \, dx\\
&=\int \frac{1}{(\sin x \cos x)^2} \, dx\\
&=\int \frac{4}{\sin^2(2x)} \, dx\\
&=\int 4 \csc^2(2x) \, dx\\
&=-2\cot(2x) +C \,.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$I = \int(\sec^2x+\csc^2x)dx = \tan x - \cot  x +c= \tan x - \frac{1}{\tan x}+c = \frac{\tan^2x-1}{\tan x}+c$$

Now $\color{blue}{\tan(2x) = \dfrac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}}$.

So,
$$I = -2\left[\frac{1-\tan^2x}{2\tan x}\right]+c=-2\frac{1}{\tan(2x)} +c= -2\cot(2x)+c$$

Comment: This is "intuitive"?

Comment: K_M has also mentioned "a short proof".